# Is reactstrap compactable with bootstrap v5

Tags: reactjs, twitter-bootstrap, next.js, react-dom, reactstrap

I got this error using reactstrap, bootstrap and nextjs

```
Server Error
SyntaxError: The requested module 'react-popper' is expected to be of type CommonJS, which does not support named exports. CommonJS modules can be imported by importing the default export.
For example:
import pkg from 'react-popper';
const { Manager, Popper, Reference } = pkg;
```

here is my package.json file

```
"@apollo/react-hooks": "^3.1.5",
"@apollo/react-ssr": "^3.1.5",
"@emotion/cache": "^11.5.0",
"@emotion/react": "^11.5.0",
"@emotion/server": "^11.4.0",
"@emotion/styled": "^11.3.0",
"@material-ui/core": "^4.12.3",
"@material-ui/icons": "^4.11.2",
"@popperjs/core": "^2.10.2",
"apollo-boost": "^0.4.7",
"apollo-link-http": "^1.5.17",
"axios": "^0.24.0",
"bootstrap": "^5.1.3",
"express": "^4.17.1",
"graphql": "^15.0.0",
"isomorphic-fetch": "^2.2.1",
"js-cookie": "^2.2.1",
"next": "^12.0.1",
"next-apollo": "^3.1.10",
"next-with-apollo": "^5.2.1",
"prop-types": "^15.7.2",
"react": "^17.0.2",
"react-dom": "^17.0.2",
"react-popper": "^2.2.5",
"reactstrap": "^9.0.0"
```

I checked online some article suggests I install react-popper and @popperjs/core which I did but it didn't work

Comment: Maybe you can take a look at https://react-bootstrap.github.io/getting-started/introduction. This is rebuilt for react and uses bootstrap v5

Comment: thanks but are they the same framework

Answer (score 3):

I encountered the same problem today. Try to update to the latest version of Node.js. That fixed the issue for me.

To confirm that you have the latest version installed type `node -v` into your terminal.

Comment: am using node v12.19.0

Comment: @SaintEverest latest stable version of node is 16.14.0 via: https://nodejs.org/en/

Answer (score 0):

I had to downgrade `reactstrap` to reactstrap": "^8.10.1 if I wanted it to work with node v12.18.3

Answer (score 0):

I also had an issue updating to Reactstrap v9 when using Next.js and Bootstrap.

Reactstrap v9 uses Bootstrap v5.

In order to update Reactstrap to v9, I had to do the following:

1. update node to latest stable version in package.json file
2. update bootstrap to version 5 in _document file: `href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"`
3. install latest version fo reactstrap by running: `npm install reactstrap@latest`